# Resuming debugging session not building changes VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++

My visual studio does not build/compile changes made under a paused debugging session.

I cannot find i reason on google for this, so i decided it is no longer my friend, and came here seeking new ones, hopefully you understand my situation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable [Edit and Continue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcew296c.aspx). This will allow you to recompile and continue running during a debug session.

Comment: I have gone into TOOLS -> OPTIONS -> DEBUGGING -> EDIT AND CONTINUE. It seems to be enabled, do i have to disable IntelliTrace?

Comment: @SuperAgentenJohannesSchaeder No, you usually don't. I can't try now, since I'm not at the office.

Comment: @SuperAgentenJohannesSchaeder Have you tried hitting compile again, before you do resume??